# How to use asynchronously subnet id in pulumi which is know after 'VirtualNetwork' object created?

Tags: pulumi

How to correctly use 'apply' in order to build 'ip_configurations' list using subnet id known after virtual network created ? Below gives  AttributeError: 'VirtualNetwork' object has no attribute 'subnet_id'

```
virtual_network = azure.network.VirtualNetwork(vnet_name, name=vnet_name, resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
    address_spaces=test_vnet['addr'], subnets=test_vnet['subnets'], location=resource_group.location)
ip_configurations = [{ "name": "ip-cfg", "subnet_id": virtual_network.subnet_id.apply(lambda subnet_id: virtual_network.subnets[0].id), 
    "privateIpAddressAllocation": "Dynamic" }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you using a separate `Subnet` resource, e.g

```
vnet = network.VirtualNetwork(
    vnet_name,
    resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
    address_spaces=["10.0.0.0/16"])

subnet = network.Subnet(
    "subnet",
    resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
    address_prefix="10.0.2.0/24",
    virtual_network_name=vnet.name,
    enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies="false")

# subnet.id
```

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/master/azure-py-vm-scaleset/__main__.py#L57-L67).

If you define `subnets` inside `VirtualNetwork`, you can access ID by looking at the `id` property of the first item in `subnets` output (`virtual_network.subnets[0].id`).